# How to access the loop variable's value outside for loop in php?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop, scope

Following is my for loop code:

```
$allFeeds = getFeedObject(null, null, $page_no, false);

            if(empty($allFeeds)) {
              for ($x = $page_no; $x <= ($page_no+10); $x++) {
                $allFeeds = getFeedObject(null, null, $x, false);
                if(count($allFeeds) > 0) {
                  $cur_page = $x;  
                  break;    
                }
              }
            }

echo $cur_page; //Here I get null
```

if I echo `$cur_page` I get null.

How to resolve this issue? How to get the value of current loop variable?

Comment: If you echo `$cur_page`  where?

Comment: @MarkBaker:See my updated question.

Comment: If you're getting `null` then $cur_page isn't being set, which probably means that $allFeeds is not empty

Comment: php variable scope is function-level. you shouldn't have to do anything special to read the variable, as long as code execution actually reached the spot where you assign a value. if that `if()` succeeds, then the variable would never get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this :

```
$allFeeds = getFeedObject(null, null, $page_no, false);

            if(empty($allFeeds)) {
              for ($x = $page_no; $x <= ($page_no+10); $x++) {
                $allFeeds = getFeedObject(null, null, $x, false);
                if(count($allFeeds) > 0) {
                  $page_no = $x;  
                  break;    
                }
              }
            }

echo $page_no;
```

isn't it ?